# Bib file, how to change year position in the reference?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using the default latex template [sn-mathphys](https://github.com/deepmaterials/dlmatreview/blob/main/dlmatreview/sn-mathphys.bst) from Spring Nature. However, it shows as

Goh, G.B., Hodas, N.O., Vishnu, A.: Deep learning for computational
chemistry. Journal of computational chemistry 38(16), 1291–1307 (2017)

I hope to move the year position ahead like this:

Goh, G.B., Hodas, N.O., Vishnu (2017), A.: Deep learning for computational
chemistry. Journal of computational chemistry 38(16), 1291–1307

Does anyone can help?!

Comment: The linked .bst  file is not a template, but a  bibliographic style. In the same git directory you have other styles, like sn-chicago, sn-apa .... Just try with these other styles. However, if you must submit the final document to a journal, most probably you should NOT change the style used in the templete (the .tex file).

Comment: @Fran Thanks for your help. I just changed sn-mathphys to sn-basic, then it works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it solved in the comments.